# What is the best way to develop a python gui for an app that has two scripts with conflicting package requirements?

Tags: python, flask, tkinter, subprocess, pyinstaller

**Problem Description**

I have two Python scripts that require conflicting package requirements. These scripts need to communicate with each other by sending and receiving a dataframe. Additionally, I want to develop a GUI for users to interact with and package the entire application for easy deployment on users' PCs or a server.

My questions are:

If I use Flask, can I create separate APIs for each script to run them in their own environments?
If I use a tool like PyInstaller, can it package the separate environments without causing conflicts?

**What I've tried so far**

I have attempted to use subprocess to interact with separate environments, which works, but I am unsure how to bundle the output effectively. I combined this approach with Tkinter for the GUI, but I am also considering developing a web-based GUI instead.

I started exploring Flask and Flask APIs, but I am uncertain whether I can specify which environment to use when running the scripts through APIs.

**Sample Code**

Here's a sample code snippet to demonstrate what i am trying to achieve:

**script two(containing the processing function):**

```
import pandas as pd

def process_dataframe(df):
    # Perform arbitrary processing on the input DataFrame
    df['new_column'] = df['existing_column'] * 2

    return df
```

**Script One (interacting with the function from "Script Two"):**

```
import pandas as pd
from script_two import process_dataframe

# Create a sample DataFrame
input_df = pd.DataFrame({'existing_column': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

# Call the processing function from "Script Two"
output_df = process_dataframe(input_df)

# Print the processed DataFrame
print(output_df)
```

Comment: Why not just resolve the conflict between the two environments?

Comment: I'm using conda environments which don't seem to be able to resolve conflicting packages well.

Comment: thats because it isn't condas job to resolve packaging conflicts.  In fact it is it's job to respect the original authors package specifications.

Comment: I see. thanks for pointing that out, are there any good resources that i can look into?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to really offer any suggestions.  That is why you are not getting an answer to your question.